# Sample code for WhatsApp interactive template message

Tags: api, postman, whatsapp

Does anyone have a sample code for WhatsApp interactive template message?

I am trying to trigger an API from postman but getting the below error:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "api_status": "stable",
        "version": "2.37.1"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 2012,
            "title": "Parameter format does not match format in the created template",
            "details": "header: Format mismatch, expected Video, received Unknown",
            "href": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/faq#faq_1612022582274564"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I added in the body:

```
{
    "to": "91NUMBER",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "namespace": "NAMESPACE_ID",
        "language": {
            "policy": "deterministic",
            "code": "en"
        },
        "name": "TEMPLATE_NAME",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "header",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "video",
                        "video": {
                            "link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/MY_VIDEO_LINK"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "url",
                "index": "0",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "9rwnB8RbYmPF5t2Mn09x4h"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

PS: I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code maybe it works

```
{
    "to": "91NUMBER",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "namespace": "NAMESPACE_ID",
        "language": {
            "policy": "deterministic",
            "code": "en"
        },
        "name": "TEMPLATE_NAME",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "header",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "video",
                        "video": {
                            "link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/MY_VIDEO_LINK"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
              {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "url",
                "index": "0",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "9rwnB8RbYmPF5t2Mn09x4h"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```